# Linear regression in the stationary case

Tags: probability, probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, linear-regression, time-series

Let $(Y_t,X_{1,t},\dots X_{K,t})$, $t=1,2,\dots$, be a jointly stationary time series on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ and taking values in $\mathbb R^{K+1}$,  and assume each component to be square integrable at each $t$.

**Question:** Does there exists $\beta \in \mathbb R^K$ and square integrable scalar time series $\varepsilon_t$ such that

$$Y_t=X_t\beta +\varepsilon_t \quad  \text{and} \quad E[X_t \varepsilon_t]=0$$

for each $t$, where $X_t:=[X_{1,t},\dots X_{K,t}]$ is a $K \times 1$ row vector?

It seems to me that the following argument works:

Define $\beta=E[X'_t X_t]^+ E[X'_tY_t] \in \mathbb R^K$, where $A^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose inverse of matrix $A$. Because of joint stationarity, we have that  $\beta$ does not depend on $t$. Moreover, from the Hilbert projection theorem in $\mathcal L^2 $ and the least-square properties of the Moore-Penrose inverse we have that

$$E[X'_tY_t]=E[X'_t X_t]\beta$$

for each $t$. Therefore if we define $\varepsilon_t:=Y_t-X_t\beta$ we get that $\varepsilon_t$ is square integrable and  $E[X_t\varepsilon_t]=0$ for each $t$.

Is this correct? Thanks a lot for your help.